# Python how to split columns each time there's a chunk of numbers in string

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, split

I have a table(dataframe) to clean up, each row looks like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | 1234 abcd 667 randomthings |
| Cell 3 | 4455 abcd abc 847 other randomthings 1 endings |

I want to split it into a table like below.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | 1234 abcd |
| Cell 1 | 667 randomthings |
| Cell 3 | 4455 abcd abc |
| Cell 3 | 847 other randomthings |
| Cell 3 | 1 endings |

So idea is the content in Column B should be split and transformed to multiple rows, and the delimiter is a chunk of random numbers (code).

I'm quite fresh with Python, and couldn't find out myself. How can I do that? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) + [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) combination:

```
df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].str.findall(r'(\d+[\s\D]+)')
df = df.explode('Column B')
```

---

```
  Column A                 Column B
0  Cell 1                1234 abcd 
0  Cell 1          667 randomthings
1  Cell 3            4455 abcd abc 
1  Cell 3   847 other randomthings 
1  Cell 3                 1 endings
```

---

In case if it's important to get rid of trailing whitespaces change regex pattern to `r'(\d+[\s\D]+[^\d\s])'` in `findall` matching. Or apply `df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].str.strip()` at the end of the first initial approach.

Comment: that's really cool! I forgot to reply earlier but it worked perfectly well, thank you!